# hello I'm trying to initialize an array on swift and I don't know what's going wrong

Tags: arrays, swift

```
import UIKit
 
var list = [2, 4, 5, 1, 0]
func initArray(array : [Int], value : Int)->[Int] {
  var arrayX = array
  for i in arrayX
  {
    arrayX[i] = value
  }
  return arrayX
}
print(initArray(array: list, value: 2))
```

I'm trying to initialize an array and Xcode respond me :

> Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:613: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: What are you expecting `initArray` to do? Create an array with 5 elements, all with the value of `2`? If so just use: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/init(repeating:count:)-5y5f0

Comment: Regarding the error, `for i in arrayX` returns items, not indices. You could `print(i)` or use the debugger and see the value.

Comment: yes ! got it... thx I thought this kind of synthax return the index.

Comment: @Frozenfrog what you are looking for is `for i in arrayX.indices`

Comment: Or `Array(repeating: 2, count: array.count)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

As mentioned by others, your crash is caused because you loop through the values in your array and try to use them as array indices.

(`for item in array` loops through the values, not the indices.)

Your loop would work if you rewrote it as

```
  for i in arrayX.indices
  {
    arrayX[i] = value
  }
```

As mentioned in Leo's comment.

Next, your function name is a bad choice. `init` is a reserved word in Swift, and you should avoid names like `init<blah>` since it implies the function is an initializer.  (You are not really initializing an array.) Your function is not an initializer. It sets your array to a new value. Actually, it doesn't even do that. It returns a new array the same size as the original array that contains a value.

As mentioned by Joakim, you could replace your entire function with

```
 let intArray = Array(repeating: 2, count: 5)
```

Or to replace the contents of an existing `intArray` var,

```
 intArray = Array(repeating: 2, count: intArray.count)
```